# Generate new column in list assigning different values by data frame from an array with lapply (R)

Tags: arrays, r, list, lapply

I have a list (*lst*) of 3 data frames, each of which includes the column (*GDP*), and an array (*countries*) with the names of 3 countries (*ARG, IT, US*), as follows:

```
lst <- list(data.frame(GDP=101:104), data.frame(GDP=1001:1003), data.frame(GDP=500:505));

countries <- array(c("ARG", "IT", "US"));
```

I want to create a new variable named *country* to be incorporated in the list so that the values from the array (*ARG, IT, US*) are "matched" to each data frame in the list.

The 3 steps I followed so far are:

1. Rename data frames included in *lst*:

> names(lst) <- countries;

2. Function to loop through with **lapply** and assign country names:

> countryvar <- function(x) {
>        x$country <- countries[i]
>        return(x)
>      };

3. Loop through the generated function *countryvar* with **lapply**:

> lst <- lapply(lst, countryvar);

My approach definitely does not work, as the new variable *country* is populated by NAs, as shown when running the following command:

> str(lst);

I guess I might not be indexing the values included in the array correctly?

Could anyone provide an efficient approach to solve this issue (ideally using **lapply**)?

Comment: Are you doing something like `setNames(lst, countries)`?  It would help if you showed the desired result

Comment: @Richard Scriven, your solution with _Map_ has worked to perfection! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @akrun I am so sorry! I am very green yet with stackoverflow and I did not even see your answer. Many thanks for your help and for letting me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 setNames(Map(`cbind`, lst, country=countries), countries)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want for the result.  Something like one of these?

```
Map(cbind, lst, country = countries)
[[1]]
  GDP country
1 101     ARG
2 102     ARG
3 103     ARG
4 104     ARG

[[2]]
   GDP country
1 1001      IT
2 1002      IT
3 1003      IT

[[3]]
  GDP country
1 500      US
2 501      US
3 502      US
4 503      US
5 504      US
6 505      US
```

Or

```
setNames(lst, countries)
```

or maybe a combination of both

```
setNames(Map(cbind, lst, country = countries), countries)
```